# Python urllib3 Error Handling

Tags: python-2.7

I'm fairly new to Python and would like some guidance on how to deal with authentication errors with urrlib3 on Python 2.7. My current use case is using SNAPI to auto create ServiceNow tickets. To do this I have the following snippet of code to use my username/password and get a token to log in.

```
r = session.post(auth_url, json=login_data, verify=False)
web_token = r.text
```

This is working fine but I want a cleaner way of notifying myself if there is an error within the code. If the username/password is incorrect, I get this back from the SN web server.

```
{
  "error": "Authentication failure"
}
```

Originally I was going to use a try/exception but it seems like that wouldn't work very well in this case since the code is working correctly, it's just not the input I was expecting. So my second thought was doing something along the lines of:

```
if r.text does not contain "error"
then continue on my doe
else send an email telling me the error code
```

Before writing the code for that, I wanted to see if this is the best method for this type of error handling or if I should be going down another route.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with a friend and he recommended the following method which seems to work very well and is a lot cleaner than doing an if/match statement.

```
try:
    r = session.post(auth_url, json=login_data, verify=False)
    web_token = r.text
    r.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```